# PHP Get datetime from database without hours/minutes?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can I get a datetime from database but without hours and minutes?
Format in database e.g 2016-03-28 15:55:00 I would like get this record if I type in SQL format y-m-d.

Comment: Use MySQL's `DATE()` function

Comment: `SELECT DATE(datetime_column) AS theDate FROM theTable`

Comment: hmm not working.. 

Select DATE(column) from table where column='2016-03-28'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't mentioned the RDBMS you're using. I presume it must be either be MySQL or SQL Server.

**MySQL:**

Here's the docoumentation in the manual : [DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)

You can use it as such (illustration) :

```
SELECT DATE('2003-12-31 01:02:03')
```

Which will yield you : `2003-12-31`

Hope this helps!!!

**EDIT : I understand you want to apply filtering on it (i.e `WHERE` clause). This is one-way you can do it.**

You can use this :

```
SELECT DATE(COLUMN_NAME)
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(COLUMN_NAME, '%Y %m %d') = DATE_FORMAT('2016-03-28', '%Y %m %d')
```

You can check it out on this fiddle here -> **[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e7b9f8/4)**

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Ya, but I have to use conditional where, e.g  SELECT DATE(column) from table where column='Y-m-d'

Comment: It's worth noting that you should be using PHP to do date formatting whenever possible and using MySQL native format for everything else. Formatting is a presentation issue and should not be done in database code, only in the PHP that does the final rendering.

Answer (score 2):

You would use `date()` in a `where` clause:

```
where date(col) = '2016-03-28'
```

Or, what is better for performance reasons (because the engine can use an index if available):

```
where date >= '2016-03-28' and
      date < date_add('2016-03-28', interval 1 day)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this SQL statement:

```
SELECT date(dateTime) From table
```